# Why does voltage cancel out if a circuit is going through a magnetic field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

[image: QUestion]

The answer says that there is no current as there is no voltage, but why is there no voltage even though they cut field lines?

EDIT; I found the answers, but still not really understanding it
[image: Answers]

Comment: I am just wondering if the line "swinging both wires together" means that there is no area between the wires. If that was the case there is no induction.

Answer (score 0):

When a conducting wire is swinging in magnetic field, induced electromotive force is generated by the change of  magnetic flux. This is for a single wire.

On the other hand, this figure seems to fold the wire. The folded wire is swinging as a single wire with 2 wires. So, the induced electromotive force is generated with same direction for 2 wires, simultaneously. I think that this is the reason of zero voltage.

If I had misunderstood, I apologize.

Comment: Its alright, i kinda get it now that they induce voltage towards the same direction, but how does that cancel out? Is it because the voltage is forcing the current to meet up and cancel?

Comment: It is considered that the distance of each wire is dur to very close at this question. If the distance is far, the induced electromotive force has a difference by the difference of magnetic flux. In the case of this, the voltage is generated by the difference.

Comment: Sorry. Strange words was included above.It is considered that the distance of each wire is very close at this question. If the distance is far, the induced electromotive force has a difference by the difference of magnetic flux. In the case of this, the voltage is generated by the difference.

Answer (score 0):

First, "cutting field lines" is an outdated concept(Faraday) regarding induction. But this is not significant here.

Swinging the folded wire doesn't induce a voltage in it because the magnetic flux enclosed by the wire is zero. If you look at it from the viewpoint of the Lorentz force on the conduction electrons moving with velocity $\vec v$ in the wire $F=e\vec v×\vec B$, there is no net EMF induced in the wire because in half of the wire $F$ is positive and in the other half negative.

Comment: Sorry i got lost with the Lorentz force part, is there a more simple way to explain this. Thanks

Comment: @Zefty - For each electron in one part of the folded wire, there is an electron next to it in the other part of the folded wire. Both electrons, moving with essentially the same speed $\vec v$ in the swinging double wire, experience the magnetic Lorentz $F$ force in the direction of  the wire but in opposite current directions in the wire. This happens for all electrons in the swinging double wire. Therefore, there is no net current at the terminals of the double wire.

Comment: I think i kind of got it. So the force acting on the electrons is f=BqV? And since there are two forces that are equal but opposite direction, they cancel? So it is kind of like a stationary car, where normal force balances out weight force?

Comment: @Zefty - For each electron experiencing the force $F=qvB$ there is one experiencing the same force but in opposite direction in the folded current loop. Therefore the currents produced by  the two electrons cancel each other. And this happens for all electrons in the folded wire loop.

Comment: Voltage (=difference of electric potential) is definitely induced between the two nodes (points where hands hold the wires). However, this voltage has largely the only effect that it counteracts the motional emf due to motion of conductor in magnetic field, in every segment of the wire, so no appreciable current flows through it.

Comment: The forces on the electrons in the parallel wires are in the same $direction$ but the opposite $sense$ around the loop.

Comment: isnt there a different formula emf= $F=I\vec l×\vec B$ where l is the length vectos along direction of current and I is the current?

Comment: @AdilMohammed that is not formula for emf, but formula for macroscopic magnetic force acting on the current-carrying wire.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy with the idea that a single wire doesn't have any current flow, then the following diagram might explain why you still get no current with two wires.

Note that there is a voltage difference betwen the two ends of the wire/tape/tapes, but it doesn't produce a current as there is no complete circuit (similarly, a battery has a voltage difference between its two ends - but no current flows).

[image]